# Uniquify all pairs in a python list

Tags: python, list, unique

I've searched through post but can't find a solution for the exact problem I face.  It's pretty easy but need a little guidance.

I have a python list that looks like:

```
lst = ['bob/sally', 'bob/chris', 'bob/nate', 'sally/bob', ...]
```

I want to iterate through and print only unique pairs.  So in the above example, it would find that bob/sally is the same as sally/bob, so it would remove one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  I've seen postings using set() and other python functions but I don't think that would work in this case.

Comment: I made your list contain strings.  I hope that's what you meant (if not, please correct it)

Answer (score 3):

You could use a set, and normalise the order of names by sorting on them:

```
>>> data = ['bob/sally', 'bob/chris', 'bob/nate', 'sally/bob']
>>> set(tuple(sorted(item.split('/'))) for item in data)
set([('bob', 'chris'), ('bob', 'nate'), ('bob', 'sally')])
```

Or as has been pointed out by [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20862/ignacio-vazquez-abrams) and [mgilson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/748858/mgilson) the use of a `frozenset` is much more elegant and eludes the sorting and tuple() step:

```
set(frozenset(item.split('/')) for item in data)
```

Comment: yep you just beat me to it, this is imho the best way to implement. - however, i would have converted it to a list at the end.

Comment: `tuple(sorted(item.split('/')))` is a little to dense for me.  I prefer the slightly simpler:  `frozenset(item.split('/'))`

Comment: @mgilson Much more elegant - I agree. I always forget about `frozenset`

Answer (score 2):

> I've seen postings using set() and other python functions but I don't think that would work in this case.

Worked fine for me...

```
>>> set([frozenset((x, y)) for (x, y) in [('bob', 'sally'), ('bob', 'nate'), ('sally', 'bob')]])
set([frozenset(['bob', 'sally']), frozenset(['bob', 'nate'])])
```

Comment: The trick here is that OP needs to use `frozenset` for the inner sets instead of `set` since `frozenset` is hashable. (+1 -- This is what I was going to post).